# x86 protected mode memory management

Tags: memory, memory-management, x86, segment, protected-mode

I'm newibe of x86 cpu.

I read all materials about memory management of protected mode in x86.

the materials are Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Volume 3A, System Programming Guide, Part 1

I believe I understand the many steps when cpu is accessing memory.
: selector register is index of segment descriptor table, and the entry of descriptor table is base of the segment, and linear address is addition of the base of the segment and 32bit offset.

But, what I'am confusing about is, it seems to me that CPU cannot know which memory address it will be access at the first time until the all steps above is finished. If CPU want to access specific memory address, It must know the selector value, and offset. But my question is how does it know ?? only information does CPU know is memory address it want to access doesn't it??

How does CPU know the input(selector value, offset) already when it only knows the output(memory address)??

Comment: The GDT address is a linear address or the CPU will incur the cyclic problem I believe you are referring to. If that's not what you're asking, can you be more precise?

Answer (score 1):

... by

- Microprocessor Real Time Clocks or Timer Chips,
- periodic function called 'clock signal'
- by Memory Controller Hub
- Advanced Configuration and Power Interface (ACPI)
- **ROM**, a non-volatile memory inside chips (RealMode Memory Map)
- *The Local Descriptor Table* (LDT) is a memory table used in the x86 architecture in protected mode and containing memory segment descriptors: start in linear memory, size, executability, writability, access privilege, actual presence in memory, etc.
- *Interrupt descriptor table*, is a data structure used by the x86 architecture to implement an interrupt vector table. The IDT is used by the processor to determine the correct response to interrupts and exceptions.
- **Intel 8259** is a Programmable Interrupt Controller (PIC) designed for the Intel 8085 and Intel 8086 microprocessors. The initial part was 8259, a later A suffix version was upward compatible and usable with the 8086 or 8088 processor. The 8259 combines multiple interrupt input sources into a single interrupt output to the host microprocessor, extending the interrupt levels available in a system beyond the one or two levels found on the processor chip

You also missing **real mode**

look also DOS_Protected_Mode_Interface & Virtual Control Program Interface

**How timer chip control reset line of CPU ?**
See also `OSCILLATOR CIRCUIT WITH SIGNAL BUFFERING AND START-UP CIRCUITRY`from Google Patents

[real time clock](https://i.stack.imgur.com/edfli.png)

The CPU 'start' executing code stored in ROM on the motherboard at address FFFF0
The routine test the central hardware, search for video ROM 
...

So.. is it not the CPU that 'start' because is power supply line that 'starts'

> The power supply signal is sent to the motherboard, where it is received by the **processor timer chip** that controls the reset line to the processor.

How does the [BIOS detect RAM](https://superuser.com/questions/974451/how-does-a-bios-determine-the-amount-of-available-ram) ? See also *serial presence detect*, power-on self-test (POST)

BIOS is a 16-bit program running in *real mode*

> The BIOS begins its POST when the CPU is reset. The first memory location the CPU tries to execute is known as the reset vector. In the case of a hard reboot, the northbridge will direct this code fetch (request) to the BIOS located on the system flash memory. For a warm boot, the BIOS will be located in the proper place in RAM and the northbridge will direct the reset vector call to the RAM

What is this reset vector ?

> The reset vector is the default location a central processing unit will go to find the **first instruction** it will execute **after a reset**. 
>   The reset vector is a pointer or address, where the CPU should always begin as soon as it is able to execute instructions. **The address is in a section of non-volatile memory** initialized to contain instructions to start the operation of the CPU, as the first step in the process of booting the system containing the CPU.
>   The reset vector for the 8086 processor is at physical address FFFF0h (16 bytes below 1 MB). The value of the CS register at reset is FFFFh and the value of the IP register at reset is 0000h to form the segmented address FFFFh:0000h, which maps to physical address FFFF0h.

About northbridge

> A northbridge or host bridge is one of the two chips in the core logic chipset architecture on a PC motherboard, the other being the southbridge. Unlike the southbridge, northbridge is connected directly to the CPU via the front-side bus (FSB)

Sources:

"80386 Programmer's Reference Manual" (PDF). Intel. 1990. Section 10.1 Processor State After Reset
 "80386 Programmer's Reference Manual" (PDF). Intel. 1990. Section 10.2.3 First Instruction,